# Constructing a Boxplot from a dataframe consisting of Multivalue columns

Tags: r

Suppose that we have a dataframe in which one of the columns represents a list of numerical data entries.

```
"ID","Costs"
"tim","1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8"
"ryan","8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1"
"bob","1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15"
```

If I wanted to construct a box-plot of costs with respect to ID, how would approach doing so?

Comment: So it's literally a bunch of text in the `Costs` column, or is it an actual `list()` object?

Comment: @thelatemail It may assumed that this data is a string of elements separated by a comma.

Comment: If this is about a regular R dataframe then you should NOT capitalize any of the letters in the term. There are other non-"data.frame"-classed objects that go by the name "DataFrame". This occurs both inside the current R universe as well as the (adjacent?) Python-universe. One could argue (and I would agree with you if you did so)  that they should not have used that sequence of letters but computer language terminology has no central authority to which we could appeal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base R solution is pretty much a one-liner, since `boxplot()` will accept a `list` as input:

```
boxplot(lapply(strsplit(dat$Costs, ",\\s+"), as.numeric), names=dat$ID)
```

[image]

`dat` in this case being:

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = c("tim", "ryan", "bob"), Costs = c("1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8", 
"8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1", "1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15")), .Names = c("ID", 
"Costs"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: You're welcome to use my graphic. They are pixel-by-pixel copies.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the data are as given in your example, *i.e.* column `Costs` contains quoted characters separated by comma + space:

```
df1 <- read.csv(text = '"ID","Costs"
"tim","1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8"
"ryan","8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1"
"bob","1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15"', 
header = TRUE, 
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then you can separate the values using `unnest`, convert to numeric and plot:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  unnest(Costs = str_split(Costs, ", ")) %>% 
  mutate(Costs = as.numeric(Costs)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(ID, Costs)) + 
    geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish this without the use of tidyverse?

Comment: Sure, it could be done using base R. My personal preference is to use tidyverse for data frame manipulation. I think it results in cleaner, easier to read code. Compare the above with something like `as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(df1$Costs, ", ")))`.

Comment: Is this the only way in which such an implementation would differ? I am fairly new to using R for statistical analysis.

Comment: I can only say that experts whose opinion I respect [recommend new users learn "tidyverse first"](http://varianceexplained.org/r/teach-tidyverse/).

Comment: My sense is that newbies who learn first  tidyverse develop a lot of bad habits relating to expectations about never having to use quotation marks. They don't really gain an understanding re: how to most effectively use the "[" and "[[" functions. There are many "experts" and I would say that most of R-Core would disagree with the tidyverse-first advice.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you want a base solution, here's one possibility:

```
boxplot( values~ind, 
       data=stack( data.frame( apply(df1, 1, # stack function converts wide to long
                function(r) setNames( 
                                list(scan(text=r[2], sep=",")), # numeric Costs
                                r[1]) ) )) )  # names then as 'ID'
```

Comment: `boxplot()` accepts `list`s too - `boxplot(lapply(strsplit(dat$Costs, ",\\s+"), as.numeric), names=dat$ID)` so you can avoid all the formula notation and `stack`-ing

Comment: Yours is both more compact and readable. Why not post it? I'm a fan of yours and have no interest in competing for points.